# C# Automatically Generate EventHandler

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a program which reads a file line by line, and put the string in a tableLayoutPanel, but how can I create an eventHandler for each label in the tableLayoutPanel?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Name = "MyNewLabel";
label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
label.Text = line;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 1);
```

Every label needs to open a webpage, and the url has to be it's own text.

I've already tried this:

```
foreach (Control x in panel1.Controls)
{
label.Click += HandleClick;
}
```

with

```
private void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
messageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}
```

It just doesn't work.

---

New Problem:

The main problem is solved by Jay Walker, but now I have another problem. Not all the labels work with the eventHandler. Here is the main code:

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("research.dat");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Name = "MyNewLabel";
    label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    label.Text = line;

    label.Click += HandleClick;

    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 1);
}
```

in combination with:

```
    private void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

Some label backgrounds change to white, and the **same** ones don't.

Comment: You are adding the labels to `tableLayoutPanel1`, however, you are looping `panel1` controls (and assigning to `label` instead of `x`, however that was commented in an answer below)... is that right?

Comment: can you elaborate on "Some label backgrounds change to white, and the **same** ones don't". What are the **same** ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add the handler when you create the label instead of later through a loop over the controls (where you should probably be referencing `x` instead of `label`.

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Name = "MyNewLabel";
label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
label.Text = line;
// add the handler here
label.Click += HandleClick;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the

```
label.Click += Eventhandler;
```

after you created the label

Answer (score 0):

if you really want it to do in the foreach loop:

```
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls) {
    if (c.Type ==  typeof(Label)) { //or something like that...
          c.Click += HandleClick;
    }
}
```